# lualatex: how to add to string or table

Tags: luatex

I want to write a "little index" now in lualatex.  all keyword content is guaranteed to occur before, and I do not want to use an external file.

My starter was:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\directlua{
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-lpeg.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-sto.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-prs.lua"))
}

\def\sort#1{%
  \directlua{\unexpanded{
    tex.sprint(
      table.concat(
        table.sorted(
          utilities.parsers.settings_to_array([[#1]]) ) , "; " ) )
}}}

\begin{document}

\sort{c, {b,x}, d, a}  %% works

% wanted:
% \addtosort{c}
% \addtosort{b,x}
% \addtosort{d}
% \addtosort{a}
% \printsorted

\end{document}
```

I am now contemplating how I should build up the list.  I can do this in tex with something like

```
\def\addkeyword#1{\g@addto@macro\mykeywords{{#1},}}$
```

and presumably then feed `\mykeywords` to `sort`.  But I am wondering what the right lualatex thing to do is.  Should I try to build up a lualatex string instead?  Or should/can I try to build a lua array, so that I do not need to parse a string to an array?

advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't quite sure how you wanted to interpret `b,x` this just treats that as a string

[image]

Each entry is added to a table, which is finally sorted and the entries returned to TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\addtosort#1{%
\directlua{
tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl,"\luaescapestring{#1}")
}}

\def\printsorted{%
\directlua{
  table.sort(tbl)
  for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do tex.write(n .. ', ') end
}}

\begin{document}

 \addtosort{c}
 \addtosort{b,x}
 \addtosort{d}
 \addtosort{a}
 \printsorted

\end{document}
```