# struggling with lualatex add to index, sort, and print

Tags: luatex

related to [lualatex: how to add to string or table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621228/lualatex-how-to-add-to-string-or-table) .  I am trying to add keywords (with page numbers) to an in-memory array, and print a sorted sequential index at the end of my chapter.  should be simple, but it's not.

I am completely puzzled about all sorts of weird errors that I am running into.  I spent some time whittling it down to where I hope an example can show off all that can go wrong:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{xifthen}  %% \isempty and \ifthenelse

\newif\ifshowproblem
\showproblemfalse

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% keyword-index.sty

%% use pageref if available; otherwise, say 'na'

\ifshowproblem
  \makeatletter
  \def\chkpageref#1{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{na}{\pageref{#1}}}
  \makeatother
\else
  \def\chkpageref#1{(not now)}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addtosort#1{%
  \directlua{%
    tbl=tbl or {}%
    table.insert(tbl,"\luaescapestring{#1}")%
  }%
}

\providecommand{\keyword}{}
%% alternative interface with optional refindex
%% needs to use \MakeLowercase later, and replace chkpageref with \chkpageref
\renewcommand{\keyword}[2][]{%
\ifshowproblem
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
    \addtosort{\textit{#2}, pg.~\chkpageref{KW:#2}}\label{KW:#2}\typeout{KWF1: #2}}{%
    \addtosort{\textit{#2}, pg.~\chkpageref{KW:#1}}\label{KW:#1}\typeout{KWF2: #1}}%
  \else
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
    \addtosort{textit{#2}, pg.~chkpageref{KW:#2}}\label{KW:#2}\typeout{KWF1: #2}}{%
    \addtosort{textit{#2}, pg.~chkpageref{KW:#1}}\label{KW:#1}\typeout{KWF2: #1}}%
  \fi
  \textbf{#2}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\printsorted{%
  \directlua{%
    table.sort(tbl)%
    for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do tex.write(n .. ';\hspace{1em} ') end%
  }}


\newcommand{\placekeywordshere}{%
  \typeout{KW: NOW SHOWING}
  \bigskip
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
  \bigskip
  \noindent\textbf{Keywords: }
  \ifshowproblem
    \printsorted
  \else
    (printsorted is not shown, because showproblem is false.)
  \fi
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{S1}

\keyword{Foxtrott} is on page 1.

\clearpage

\section{S2}

\keyword{BRAVO} and others are on page 2.

\keyword[xind]{x-Ray \& Co to the end}

\keyword{Alpha to the front}.

\section{EOC Material}

\placekeywordshere

\section{EOC WANTED}

\bigskip
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{Keywords: }
alpha to the front, pg.~2; \hspace{1em} bravo, pg.~2; \hspace{1em} foxtrott, pg.~1; \hspace{1em} x-ray \& co to the end, pg.~2.


\end{document}
```

switch on `showproblem` and everything that can go wrong seems to be going wrong.  I think it is both tex and lua stuff I am butchering, and this makes it difficult to track.   apologies for so much of an imposition. advice highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a page break between the last keyword and the point you print them out, you can skip the aux file and requiring two runs of latex.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addtosort#1{%
  \latelua{%
    tbl=tbl or {}%
    table.insert(tbl,"{\luaescapestring{#1}}{\thepage}")%
  }%
}

\providecommand{\keyword}{}
%% alternative interface with optional refindex
%% needs to use \MakeLowercase later, and replace chkpageref with \chkpageref
\renewcommand{\keyword}[1]{#1 \addtosort{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\printsorted{%
  \directlua{%
    table.sort(tbl)%
    for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    tex.print("\string\\printkw" .. n)
     end%
  }}

\newcommand\printkw[2]{\textit{#1} pg #2;}

\newcommand{\placekeywordshere}{%
  \typeout{KW: NOW SHOWING}
  \bigskip
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
  \bigskip
  \section*{Keywords: }
    \printsorted
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{S1}

\keyword{Foxtrott} is on page 1.

\clearpage

\section{S2}

\keyword{BRAVO} and others are on page 2.

\keyword{x-Ray \& Co to the end}

\keyword{Alpha to the front}.

\clearpage
\section{EOC Material}

\placekeywordshere

\section{EOC WANTED}

\bigskip
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
\bigskip
\section*{Keywords: }
alpha to the front, pg.~2; \hspace{1em} bravo, pg.~2; \hspace{1em} foxtrott, pg.~1; \hspace{1em} x-ray \& co to the end, pg.~2.


\end{document}
```

---

version sorting on lower case

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addtosort#1{%
  \latelua{%
    tbl=tbl or {}%
    table.insert(tbl,"{" .. string.lower("\luaescapestring{#1}") .. "}{\luaescapestring{#1}}{\thepage}")%
  }%
}

\providecommand{\keyword}{}
%% alternative interface with optional refindex
%% needs to use \MakeLowercase later, and replace chkpageref with \chkpageref
\renewcommand{\keyword}[1]{#1 \addtosort{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\printsorted{%
  \directlua{%
    table.sort(tbl)%
    for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    tex.print("\string\\printkw" .. n)
     end%
  }}

\newcommand\printkw[3]{\par\noindent\textit{#2} pg #3;\par}% discard lowercase #1 used for sort

\newcommand{\placekeywordshere}{%
  \typeout{KW: NOW SHOWING}
  \bigskip
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
  \bigskip
  \section*{Keywords: }
    \printsorted
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{S1}

\keyword{Foxtrott} is on page 1.

\clearpage

\section{S2}

\keyword{BRAVO} and others are on page 2.

\keyword{x-Ray \& Co to the end}

\keyword{Alpha to the front}.
\keyword{alpha lower case to the front}.

\clearpage
\section{EOC Material}

\placekeywordshere

\section{EOC WANTED}

\bigskip
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
\bigskip
\section*{Keywords: }
alpha to the front, pg.~2; \hspace{1em} bravo, pg.~2; \hspace{1em} foxtrott, pg.~1; \hspace{1em} x-ray \& co to the end, pg.~2.


\end{document}
```

Comment: it's lovely.  changes from mine: `\latelua` waits until page gets shipped out, simplifying *everything*.  Question: how does lualatex pass two arguments to latex `\printkw{}`?

Comment: see in the insert I store two brace groups in the string in each table entry `{\luaescapestring{#1}}   {\thepage}` @ivoWelch

Comment: I see.  Grazie.  I need lowercase search ordering,  `addtosort` just drops in the literal, so `\MakeLowercase{#1}` in `\addtosort` does not work.  I tried `\def\addtosort#1{\addtosortb{\expandafter\MakeLowercase{#1}}}`, where `\addtosortb` is the previous definition---but it doesn't like me.  sorry, more help :-(

Comment: @ivoWelch you could do it in Lua `string.lower(s) ` lowercases  `s`

Comment: yes, but where and how do I stick it in?  (I think I need a sort of lualatex cookbook to have starting recipes.  right now, I am trying to piece this together, but there are a lot of magic aspects to it and I think that some syntax has changed over the years.)  david, would it be possible to revise the solution to add this, please?

Comment: sorry had go out and watch some fireworks:-) remember remember the ---5th--- 6th of November...

Comment: @ivoWelch version with string.lower() added

Comment: mille grazie, again.  looking at your code, I stood no chance of figuring this out myself.  (For learning, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500394/resources-for-learning-lua-programming .)